# What does MATLAB display when plotting a sound signal?

Tags: matlab, sound, speech

When  you load the speech file 'mtlb' in MATLAB (which is by the way the voice of a woman saying the word 'MATLAB'), and plot the data, you get the following plot:
[image]

My question is this: what does the y-axis represent? What is MATLAB actually plotting here? Thanks!

Comment: It's just plotting the sample values - so it's somewhat like an oscilloscope display in the real world.

Comment: @PaulR OK. but what do those sample values measure? intensity? amplitude?... This is where I am confused. For example an oscilloscope in an electric circuit may measure voltage. But what about sound?

Comment: Sound pressure waves are converted to a voltage signal by a microphone. This analogue voltage signal is then sampled by an A-D converter, giving you discrete sample values which can be plotted as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are observing is the digital representation of the voltage, which in fact represents the acoustic pressure.
Workflow would be something like:

- Vibrating larynx is producing `Acoustic Pressure [Pa]`
- Variations of that pressure are converted by the microphone into `Voltage [V]`
- Voltage is being sampled and quantized by the ADC (Analog to Digital Converter) and represented as series of numbers.

Now knowing your microphone's sensitivity `[mV/Pa]` you can relate the voltage and acoustic pressure. Additionally if ADC's parameters are known (or measured) then you can directly relate sample values to Pascals.